# Adding to a Vector the value contained in another Vector... Will a change in one reflect in another? 

Tags: java, vector, pass-by-reference

I have the following two `Vector` objects in java.

```
Vector<SomeClass> obj1;
Vector<SomeClass> obj2;
```

The class SomeClass has an int variable `a`.

Assume `obj2` is empty and `obj1` has some elements in it. Suppose I do this:

```
obj2.add(obj1.firstElement()); 
obj2.firstElement().a = 10;  // obj2.firstElement() will be the object that was 
                             //added above because obj2 was empty at first
```

Would this change the value of a in `obj1.firstElement()` too?

Basically I just want to know if these `Vector` operations are done by reference or value. My guess is that they are done by reference and this change will be reflected in `obj1.firstElement()` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the reference is copied (shallow copy) and so the change is reflected also in the original vector.

Answer (score 0):

Although is was probably quicker to test this yourself in code then to post it here, you have guessed correctly